# Вывести общее количество данных с item в zabbix

Tags: zabbix

Добрый день. Подскажите можно ли вывести в график количество данных за период (допустим 7 дней) с конкретного item.

Comment: сделал это через запрос в базу заббикса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

сделал это через запрос в базу заббикса. в таблице history.